# How do I determine the proper bonuses for my attack and damage rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, ranged-attack, dnd-beyond

I am a half-orc monk at level 14. I am using a homebrew gun called "the demon of powder", which has 6 charges that it expends as ammunition instead of regular bullets. My stats are 14 20 14 8 15 10 in order.

The description of the weapon says I get +5 to both hit and damage rolls, but on dndbeyond it says I have +6 to hit and 2d8+6 for damage. My DM said that the regular damage for this weapon is 2d8.

I'm very confused where dndbeyond is getting the bonuses of +6 from.

Additionally, I am wondering if I should manually add in the +5 to hit from the description or if it is already included?

https://www.dndbeyond.com/profile/yompog/characters/28500037
that's my link, idk if that works for others. This is for dnd 5e .

I do not have proficiency with guns, although the DM has stated that for the sake of the story I am automatically able to use the gun to its fullest potential. The equivalent story-related thing closest to gun proficiency is that it requires attunement.

Comment: Guns have only limited official rule support, so it's not too shocking to me that official tools like D&D Beyond might be confused by yours. Is your monk proficient in firearms? Is the +5 in the description some kind of magical effect (e.g. a +1 sword has a +1 to both attack and damage rolls), or is it supposed to be describing the final modifiers you have, after your attributes and proficiency are included? I'm not sure there are any 5e weapons with +5 magic bonuses, that seems like it could break the game's bounded accuracy design.

Comment: OK, I've added the dndbeyond link, hopefully that works. Thanks for your time anyway guys!

Comment: There should be a customise tab on the item (for you, not for us as viewers). You might want to include a screenshot of it so we can tell what the D&D Beyond implementation of the item it.

Answer (score 2):

The description of your magic weapon, *Demon of Powder* says:

> You gain a +5 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon.

So we are up to a +5 bonus to your attack roll and +5 to your damage roll.

From the rules for making an attack, we have two things that come into play:

> **Ability Modifier.** The ability modifier used for a melee weapon attack is Strength, and the *ability modifier used for a ranged weapon attack is Dexterity*.

And,

> **Proficiency Bonus.** You add your proficiency bonus to your attack roll when you attack using *a weapon with which you have proficiency*, as well as when you attack with a spell.

From the linked character sheet, it does not appear that you have proficiency with firearms or the *Demon of Powder*, so we do not add your proficiency bonus to attack rolls.

We are now up to a +10 to your attack roll: +5 (Dexterity modifier) plus +5 (*Demon of Powder*).

From the rules for Damage rolls,

> When attacking with a weapon, you add your ability modifier — the same modifier used for the attack roll — to the damage.

So this would add your Dexterity modifier to the damage of *Demon of Powder*, giving us a total of +10 (+5 Dexterity and +5 *Demon of Powder*).

I'm not seeing anything else on your character sheet that would modify these numbers, so your attacks with *Demon of Powder* should be **+10 to hit with 2d8+10 damage**.

It appears as though *Demon of Powder* is not a publicly available homebrew item on DND Beyond, so I can't tell you why the numbers appear different than expected. But you can adjust the numbers by customizing the "To Hit Bonus" and "Damage Bonus" in the customization option for actions on your character sheet.

Based on the numbers DND Beyond is currently displaying, these settings should correct it:

[image]

Comment: I would posit that the gun is (for some reason) not actually utilizing the Dex bonus and is instead pulling a bonus from elsewhere. It would line up more with the math too. +5 (weapon) +5 (prof) +1 (other source) = +11 to hit, and +5 (weapon) +1 (other source) = +6 to damage. Problem is, I can't figure out what the +1 is from, since he doesn't have a single stat with a +1 modifier.